# How can i return a list from retrofit onResponse?

Tags: java, android, list, return, retrofit

I've seen a few similar questions but they don't seem to answer my problem exactly. I'm pulling a list with Retrofit and I want to export it to a list and create a listview. But I am not getting any return from onResponse. I've also tried returning a list directly with return. Please help.

this is the callback func

listCatcher just holds a list

Ibreeds is interface

```java
public ListCatcher allBreeds(View view){
        ArrayList<String> breedList = new ArrayList<>(breeds);

        Ibreeds.allBreeds().enqueue(new Callback<Breeds>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Breeds> call, Response<Breeds> response) {
                List<String> breeds = response.body().getMessage();

                for (String b: breeds){
                    breedList.add(b);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Breeds> call, Throwable t) {
                Snackbar.make(view,R.string.connectionStatus, 3000 ).show();
            }
        });

        ListCatcher listcatcher = new ListCatcher(breedList);
        return listcatcher;
    }
```

```java
public interface BreedsDAOInterface {

    @GET("breeds/list")
    Call<Breeds> allBreeds();

    @GET("breed/{breed}/list")
    Call<Breeds> listSubBreed(@Path("breed") String breed);

    @GET("breed/{breed}/images")
    Call<Breeds> listBreedImages(@Path("breed") String breed);

    @GET("breed/{breed}/{subBreed}/images")
    Call<Breeds> listSubBreedImages(@Path("breed") String breed, @Path("subBreed") String subBreed);

    @GET("breeds/image/random")
    Call<Breeds> iFeelLucky();

}
```

```java
public class ApiUtils {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://dog.ceo/api/";

    public static BreedsDAOInterface getBreedsDaoInterface(){
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(BreedsDAOInterface.class);
    }

}
```

```java
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseURL){
        if (retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit
                    .Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseURL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Breeds {

    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private List<String> message;


    public List<String> getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(List<String> message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

EDIT

I found the solution to the problem:
listCatcher deleted

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<String> breedsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private BreedsInterface Ibreeds;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter RWAdapter;
    private ActivityHomeBinding binding;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        Ibreeds = ApiUtils.getBreedsDaoInterface();
        allBreeds();

    }

    public void allBreeds(){

        Ibreeds.allBreeds().enqueue(new Callback<Answer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Answer> call, Response<Answer> response) {
                List<String> breedResponceList = response.body().getMessage();
                breedsList.clear();
                breedsList.addAll(breedResponceList);
                initRecyclerView();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Answer> call, Throwable t) {
                throwError();
            }
        });
    }


    private void throwError() {
        Snackbar.make(binding.getRoot(), R.string.connectionStatus, 3000).show();
    }

    private void initRecyclerView() {
        RWAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(breedsList);
        binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(RWAdapter);
    }

}
```

I added the adapter to the enqueue function via a function

Comment: "But I am not getting any return from onResponse" -- you probably should explain more what you mean by this. Your `ListCatcher` may not be useful, as you create and return it long before you get a response from your Web service.

Comment: Yes, onResponse was running in the background much later. What should I do for it? I need to take the contents of this list and put it in another list in main. @CommonsWare

Comment: onResponse is working but running too late. Is there no way to run it inside main thread?

Comment: "What should I do for it?" -- your Retrofit code should be in something like a Jetpack `ViewModel`, and it should update something like a `MutableLiveData` with the results. Your UI code can observe the `LiveData` and react when the list is available. Modern books and courses on Android app development will cover these sorts of techniques. For example, I demonstrate the use of Retrofit this way in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-internet-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack).